# How to pass Array object from one activity to another activity, without serializable extras?

Tags: java, android

I having an array of object in one activity, after hitting webservice with JSON response in AsyncTask - doInBackground . Kindly give a suggestions to pass values between activity without serializable.

Comment: You want to pass an array using intents?

Comment: Try out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417251/passing-arrayobject-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: Creating a Singleton class is better option rather than using Serializable.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323180/passing-dataset-between-activity-in-mpandroidchart/50323681#50323681

Comment: Thanks bro.It worked well @hasan_shaikh

Comment: If it worked for you, then you can upvote that answer. so that it will be useful for others who come across the same issue